# LCM of 2 strings

Tags: c++, string, append, lcm

I have to find the LCM of 2 strings given that a multiplication operation exists between a number and a string which dictates that if x is a number and s is a string, then s*x is equal to the string s taken x times.

the strings given are "baba" and "ba". Now I am having trouble even getting started with this because I have to print -1 if the LCM does not exist.

Please help with this. I am just a beginner in c++.

Comment: Show your code and clearly indicate what you have problems with and someone may be able to help you.

Comment: what help do you need? What did you try? Is your code not doing what you want it to do? Do you have any code? [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I coded a function which appends the string s to itself n times and returns it

Comment: If this LCM exists, then its length is the LCM of the two lenghts. This may help...

Comment: Thank you! That helps. I will try to devise a solution and post the code here.

Comment: How can I check if the LCM does not exist

Comment: (Note: if you ask a question to someone use @Name). You know the size `n = lcm(n1, n2)` of the possible LCM string. You have to check that `s1[i%n1] == s2[i%n2]`, for all `i` from `0` to `n-1`, to check that this LCM exists. In other words, you have to check that `p*s1 == q*s2`, where `p*n1 = q*n2 = lcm(n1, n2)`

Comment: I am sorry @Damien, I forgot to tag you here. I found a solution which I tested for a number of test cases and was correct for all of them. I will post the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lcm of the two strings can be found by calculating the lcm of their lengths (Thank you @Damien for this).

```
int gcd(int a, int b){
    if (b==0)
    {
        return a;
    }
    return gcd(b,a%b);
}

int lcm(int a,int b){
    return (a/gcd(a,b))*b;
}
```

After you have the lcm of their lengths, then you append each string to itself until the strings are of the same length as the lcm of their lengths.

```
string StringLCM(string s,int n){
    string result = s;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        result.append(s);
    }
    return result;
}
```

THe StringLCM function returns the strings of length equal to the LCM.
Now just compare the 2 strings and check if they are equal or not. THe program prints -1 if no LCM can be found.
Below is the complete code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int gcd(int a, int b){
    if (b==0)
    {
        return a;
    }
    return gcd(b,a%b);
}

int lcm(int a,int b){
    return (a/gcd(a,b))*b;
}

string StringLCM(string s,int n){
    string result = s;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        result.append(s);
    }
    return result;
}
 
int main(){
    string s1 = "aba";
    string s2 = "ab";
    int n1= s1.length();
    int n2= s2.length();
    int l=lcm(n1,n2);  
    cout<<l<<endl;
    int flag=0;
    int e =-1;

    s1=StringLCM(s1,l/n1);
    cout<<s1<<endl;
    s2=StringLCM(s2,l/n2);
    cout<<s2<<endl;

    if (s1==s2)
    {
        flag=1;
    }
    if (flag==1)
    {
        cout<<s1<<endl;
    }else
    {
        cout<<e<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can simplify the last block via `if (s1 == s2) std::cout << s1; else std::cout << -1;`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818. Thank you. I will modify it accordingly